# Trying to Join these four nested subqueries.

Tags: sql-server

```
(select * 
from (select encounterId as 'EncounterID', dateOfBirth as 'PatientDateOfBirth', SexCodeId as 'PatientSexNameCodeID' from AlphaPatientDemographics ) as a
join (select id as 'PatientSexNameCodeID', label as 'PatientSexNameCodeLabel',symbol as 'PatientSexNameCodeSymbol', system as 'PatientSexNameCodeSystem' from AlphaCode ) as b
on a.PatientSexNameCodeID = b.PatientSexNameCodeID )

(select *
from (select encounterId as 'EncounterID',ethnicityCodeId as 'PatientEthnicityNameCodeID' from AlphaPatientDemographics ) as c
join ( select id as 'PatientEthnicityCodeNameID', label as 'PatientEthnicityNameCodeLabel',symbol as 'PatientEthnicityNameCodeSymbol', system as 'PatientEthnicityNameCodeSystem' from AlphaCode ) as d
on c.PatientEthnicityNameCodeID = d.PatientEthnicityCodeNameID)

(select * 
from (select encounterId as 'EncounterID',raceCodeId as 'PatientRaceNameCodeID' from AlphaPatientDemographics ) as e
join (select id as 'PatientRaceNameCodeID', label as 'PatientRaceNameCodeLabel',symbol as 'PatientRaceNameCodeSymbol', system as 'PatientRaceNameCodeSystem' from AlphaCode ) as f
on e.PatientRaceNameCodeID = f.PatientRaceNameCodeID) 

(select *
from (select encounterId as 'EncounterID',maritalStatusCodeId as 'PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeID' from AlphaPatientDemographics) as g
join (select id as 'PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeID', label as 'PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeLabel',symbol as 'PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeSymbol', system as 'PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeSystem' from AlphaCode ) as h
on g.PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeID = h.PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeID)
```

Order by
encounterId, PatientDateOfBirth, PatientSexCodeId, PatientSexNameCodelabel, PatientSexNameCodeSymbol, PatientSexNameCodeSystem, PatientEthinicityCodeId, PatientEthnicityNameCodelabel, PatientEthnicityNameCodeSymbol, PatientEthnicityNameCodeSystem, PatientRaceCodeId,PatientRaceNameCodelabel,PatientRaceNameCodeSymbol,PatientRaceNameCodeSystem,PatientMaritalStatusCodeId, PatientMaritalStatusNameCodelabel, PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeSymbol,PatientMaritalNameCodeSystem

Trying to join these four nested subqueries. order by
encounterId, PatientDateOfBirth, PatientSexCodeId, PatientSexNameCodelabel, PatientSexNameCodeSymbol, PatientSexNameCodeSystem, PatientEthinicityCodeId, PatientEthnicityNameCodelabel, PatientEthnicityNameCodeSymbol, PatientEthnicityNameCodeSystem, PatientRaceCodeId,PatientRaceNameCodelabel,PatientRaceNameCodeSymbol,PatientRaceNameCodeSystem,PatientMaritalStatusCodeId, PatientMaritalStatusNameCodelabel, PatientMaritalStatusNameCodeSymbol,PatientMaritalNameCodeSystem
Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you want to join them? It probably would've been easier to show us table samples instead. Do you have a desired result to show us?

Comment: Something more than a wall of text is needed here.

Comment: trying join each nested subquery on EncounterId